What's the difference between these two attacks?(Lim Lee and Sub group) I am a beginner can someone explain in detail?
I am reading collin boyd textbook to learn MTI key agreement and various attacks on them . I encountered two such attacks called Small sub group attack and Lim-Lee attack where in
Small sub group attack :
sub group works on the whole group itself (p-1) and reducing search space by pushing the value ( w = p-1/r. , powering with w) to a small order and then conducting exhaustive search among elements which has this order in the whole group

Lim -Lee :


The first one is a tree party, in the second, party C uses the small group to extract information. I think you need to separate this question. Pohlig Hellman and small subgroup attacks

In the first instance we have two legitimate users $A$ and $B$ attempting to establish an ephemeral one-time shared secret key using their both static long term public private pairs $(x_A,y_A=g^{x_A})$ and $(x_B,y_B=g^{x_B})$ and short term ephemeral values $r_A$ and $r_B$. We assume that $y_A$ and $y_B$ have been pre-shared and the intended protocol is intended to settle on the shared ephemeral key $g^{x_Ax_Br_Ar_B}=y_A^{x_Br_Ar_B}=y_B^{x_Ar_Ar_B}=z_A^{r_B}=z_B^{r_A}$ where $z_A=y_A^{x_Br_B}$ and $z_B=y_B^{x_Ar_A}$ with information exchanged as follows
$${{\tiny z_A}\atop\longrightarrow}$$
$${{\tiny z_B}\atop\longleftarrow}.$$
The scheme is attacked by the active adversary $C$ who cause both sides to compute a shared secret value with low entropy via a man-in-the-middle attack. $C$ achieves this by replacing $z_A$ and $z_B$ with their $w$th powers (which both lie in a subgroup of order $r$ so that the final shared secret value lies in subgroup of order $r$.
In the second instance, the attack is on an authenticated key exchange algorithm per section 2.2 of the Lim Lee paper. The protocol again uses long-term static pairs $(x_A,y_A=g^{x_A})$ and $(x_B,y_B=g^{x_B})$ and short term ephemeral values $r_A$ and $r_B$. We again assume that $y_A$ and $y_B$ have been pre-shared. The ephemeral shared value $g^{x_Ar_B+x_Br_A}$ is intended to be formed with information exchanged
$${{\tiny t_A=g^{r_A}}\atop\longrightarrow}$$
$${{\tiny t_B=g^{r_B}}\atop\longleftarrow}.$$
In this case the user $C$ is attempting to obtain information about the long term secret value $x_B$ by pretending to be a legitimate user. They generate $t_A$, but instead transmit $\beta t^a$ which lies in a coset of the subgroup of order $q$ rather the subgroup itself. This causes $B$ to compute a version of the shared secret value that is shifted by an amount $x_B\mod r$. By exhausting over possible shifts, $C$ can then learn $x_B\mod r$. Repeating this for several $r$ values could be enough to recover $X_B$ itself.
Comparing the two attacks we see that the first is an active ephemeral shared-key compromise on an exchange where both users are legitimately fulfilling their roles; the second is part of an attack to recover a users static private key by $C$ pretending to by a legitmate user, but abusing their role.

Lim Lee attack is still confusing , if its possible can you elaborate more ?
